# Problem opening views

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cab

I sometimes get this error message when I'm trying to open a view and the only way I've been able to fix it is if I close and restart Visual Studio, Is anyone familiar with this problem. It's in a CAB project

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Infrastructure.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess know one knows, so I'm stuck with restarting it then.